# Delegate translations to non developers

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I'm using Django 1.5 and would like to delegate the translation to people who are not developer.

I imagine a simple web editor displaying readonly **msgid** with each related editable **msgstr**.

This editor would allow to select the target language and do the validations on submit.

Is there something similar existing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe  that your requirements are covered by django-rosetta (https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta).

Copying from the project README:

> Rosetta is a Django application that eases the translation process of
>   your Django projects.
>
> - Database independent
> - Reads and writes your project's gettext catalogs (po and mo files)
> - Installed and uninstalled in under a minute
> - Uses Django's admin interface CSS